# Imposm how to import a new osm .pbf without erasing an existing db?

Tags: osm.pbf, imposm

I have an existing PostgreSQL db in which I had imported OSM data extracts in .pbf format for North America.

Suppose that I now need to import a new .pbf file for Europe in the dame db.

How can I make sure it doesn't erase my existing tables with North American data?

I tried:

`imposm import -config ./imposm.conf -read ./europe.pbf -appendcache`

and then:

`imposm import -write -config ./imposm.conf`

But this resets all the tables in my existing database.

I couldn't find any info on this in the [Imposm documentation](https://imposm.org/docs/imposm3/latest/index.html)